# New project is not included in local publish using TDS

Tags: tds, web-deploy

I'm working on an existing Visual Studio solution which uses TDS.

I have added a new class library project in the `Foundation` layer namely `MyProject.Foundation.Accounts`. This project is not referenced in any of the other projects.  It is only used in a patch config.

When I right-click on the Solution and choose `Deploy Solution` to publish files in my local instance, the new dll `MyProject.Foundation.Accounts.dll` is not published.

There is a `MyProject.Build` TDS project. When I check its properties (General), the `Source Web Projects` field lists all projects except for the new one.

How to include my new project and also, should the step be done for every new project.

**Update :**
The Configuration properties has Build checked and Deploy disabled for both Release & Debug.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the `Save All` option after adding your project in Visual Studio? And then re-open the properties.

Comment: @Qwerty removing a failing project from the solution and then adding it back

Answer (score 2):

Set the Build and Deploy Settings in Configuration Manager.  Select your project and check **Build** checkbox in your active solution configuration that is selected in the above first dropdown.  Do this for all of the build configurations.

[image]

Try if this works for you.

Check this for more reference - https://blogs.perficient.com/2013/12/08/setting-up-a-sitecore-solution-part-2-tds-and-build-configurations/

Comment: The Build was already checked and Deploy checkbox is disabled for both debug & release. I have updated the snap in my question.